# Run the command in the script after waking up in Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, pulseaudio, suspend

I have such a malfunction: after coming out of sleep, the sound disappears on the PC (in chromium). It can be solved if you type the `pulseaudio -k` command in the terminal. But in order not to enter it every time, I made a script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
pulseaudio -k
```

I did everything as in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/661747/1762830), but it didn't work. I get the message in the log:

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: The daemon could not shut down: There is no such process
```

At the same time, if you enter it in the console after that: `pulseaudio -k`, the command is executed without error and the sound appears.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.

User service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run my_script_pulse
After=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
#After=sleep.target

[Service]
#Type=oneshot
#Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/st_pulse
#ExecStart=/home/paul/st_pulse.sh
#User=paul
#Environment=DISPLAY=:0
StandardOutput=file:/home/paul/log_file

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
#WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Comment: On `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service`, I get: `Failed to connect to bus: There is no such file or directory`

Comment: Although I suspect it's because I haven't created a custom service. Then I'll try to do it later.

Comment: I have created a custom service (see p.s.), but it does not start after waking up. And judging by this answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174837/514842), in principle, this method is not supported by the system. I mean, the user does not have access to system processes such as suspend.target.

Comment: See if this helps: [pulseaudio_suspend](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#No_sound_after_resume_from_suspend)

Comment: don-crissti No.

Comment: Well, there's also [this_one](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=245352) which is similar to what you have in your script... if that doesn't work either then I don't know what else to advise. Sorry.

Comment: don-crissti thanks for the reply. I'll try it later. But so far, all these user services don't even start when PC wake up from sleep. In principle, this is not particularly critical, because it is treated from the command line. In my free time, I try to play with different parameters.